# How to handle 404 when using @RequestMapping for Restful api call

Tags: spring

I am spring mvc's @RequestMapping and @Pathvariable. I have the following code in the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/addOwners")
@ResponseBody
public class MyLibraryController {
    @RequestMapping(value="`enter code here`/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId) {
    String owner = ownerService.addOwner(ownerId);
    return "successful";
}
```

The code works fine when this url is used http://localhost:8080/api/addOwners/owners/7, but returns a 404 for this http://localhost:8080/api/addOwners/owners/ . Basically the value is not passed.

How do I handle this error?

Comment: The PathVariable must be present. If not you have to handle it with additional Handler Method. In your Case @RequestMapping(value="/owners"...)

Comment: any examples or documents on how to do it? I am kind of new and getting to learn as much as possible. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle exception explicitly in your spring controller. There are different way to handle it but I prefer to do it using custom method to handle 
    error on the controller with the help of **@ExceptionHandler** and **@ResponseStatus** annotations. Please go through the below links for detail

[Spring REST: Exception handling vol. 1](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-rest-exception-handling-1/)

Hope this information will help you :)